# How to add a new column when writing to a Delta table?

Tags: python, apache-spark, delta-lake, data-lakehouse, delta-rs

I am using [delta-rs](https://github.com/delta-io/delta-rs) to write to a Delta table in the Delta Lake. Here is my code:

```py
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
from deltalake.writer import write_deltalake

num_rows = 10
timestamp = np.array([time.time() + i * 0.01 for i in range(num_rows)])
current = np.random.rand(num_rows) * 10
voltage = np.random.rand(num_rows) * 100
temperature = np.random.rand(num_rows) * 50
data = {
    "timestamp": timestamp,
    "current": current,
    "voltage": voltage,
    "temperature": temperature,
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
storage_options = {
    "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION": "us-west-2",
    "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": "xxx",
    "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "xxx",
    "AWS_S3_ALLOW_UNSAFE_RENAME": "true",
}
schema = pa.schema(
    [
        ("timestamp", pa.float64()),
        ("current", pa.float64()),
        ("voltage", pa.float64()),
        ("temperature", pa.float64()),
    ]
)
write_deltalake(
    "s3a://my-bucket/delta-tables/motor",
    df,
    mode="append",
    schema=schema,
    storage_options=storage_options,
)
```

Above code successfully wrote the data including 4 columns to a Delta table. I can confirm by Spark SQL:

```bash
spark-sql> describe table delta.`s3a://my-bucket/delta-tables/motor`;
23/05/22 06:38:51 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database delta, returning NoSuchObjectException
timestamp             double
current               double
voltage               double
temperature           double

# Partitioning
Not partitioned
Time taken: 0.39 seconds, Fetched 7 row(s)

spark-sql> select * from delta . `s3a://my-bucket/delta-tables/motor` limit 10;
23/05/22 07:01:50 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database delta, returning NoSuchObjectException
1.683746477029865E9 7.604250297497938 9.421758439102415 72.1927369069416
1.683746477039865E9 0.09092487512480374 17.989035574705202  35.350210012093214
1.683746477049866E9 7.493128659573002 9.390891728445448 48.541259705334625
1.683746477059866E9 2.717780962917138 0.9268887657049119  59.10566692023579
1.683746477069866E9 2.57300442470119  17.486083607683693  47.23521355609355
1.683746477079866E9 2.09432242350117  14.945888123248054  47.125030870747715
1.683746477089866E9 4.136491853926207 16.52334128991138 27.544656909406505
1.6837464770998669E9  1.1299759566741152  5.539831633892187 52.50892511866684
1.6837464771098669E9  0.9626607062002979  8.400536671329352 72.49131313291358
1.6837464771198668E9  7.6866231204656446  4.033915109232906 48.900631068812075
Time taken: 5.925 seconds, Fetched 10 row(s)
```

Now I am trying to write to the Delta table with a new column `pressure`:

```py
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
from deltalake.writer import write_deltalake

num_rows = 10
timestamp = np.array([time.time() + i * 0.01 for i in range(num_rows)])
current = np.random.rand(num_rows) * 10
voltage = np.random.rand(num_rows) * 100
temperature = np.random.rand(num_rows) * 50
pressure = np.random.rand(num_rows) * 1000
data = {
    "timestamp": timestamp,
    "current": current,
    "voltage": voltage,
    "temperature": temperature,
    "pressure": pressure,
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
storage_options = {
    "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION": "us-west-2",
    "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": "xxx",
    "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "xxx",
    "AWS_S3_ALLOW_UNSAFE_RENAME": "true",
}
schema = pa.schema(
    [
        ("timestamp", pa.float64()),
        ("current", pa.float64()),
        ("voltage", pa.float64()),
        ("temperature", pa.float64()),
        ("pressure", pa.float64()), # <- I added this line
    ]
)
write_deltalake(
    "s3a://my-bucket/delta-tables/motor",
    df,
    mode="append",
    schema=schema,
    storage_options=storage_options,
    overwrite_schema=True, # <- Whether add this or not will return same error
)
```

Note whether adding `overwrite_schema=True` in the function `write_deltalake` does not affect the result.

It will throw this error:

```bash
...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python3.11/site-packages/deltalake/writer.py", line 180, in write_deltalake
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Schema of data does not match table schema

Table schema:
timestamp: double
current: double
voltage: double
temperature: double
pressure: double

Data Schema:
timestamp: double
current: double
voltage: double
temperature: double
```

This error confused me. Because my existing Delta table data schema should have 4 columns. And the new data I want to write has 5 columns. But based on the error, it is opposite.

How can I add a new column in a Delta table? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, this feature is not supported.

Here is the feature request ticket https://github.com/delta-io/delta-rs/issues/1386

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need `mode='overwrite'` to use `overwrite_schema=True`. (See the [source code](https://github.com/delta-io/delta-rs/blob/6799d2e584399f9c16437e5418d8d8e4aedfa385/python/deltalake/writer.py#L178))

It doesn't seem to be documented well. If you want to add a column when you append, you'd need to overwrite the existing data first, adding the column, and then run the append statement.

Comment: Thanks @s_pike , but `mode='overwrite'` will cause all data in the Delta table "lost", right? Is there a way not losing data? Because all new columns can be optional.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I can't see a way to add a column using `delta_rs`, without reading, editing and then overwriting. Delta table does support it, via the `mergeSchema` option: https://delta.io/blog/2023-02-08-delta-lake-schema-evolution/